# Proxify LinkedIn Scraper gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Using the [LinkedIn Scraper Gem](https://github.com/yatish27/linkedin-scraper) and having some trouble with proxifying it.
It works great on local and no problems at all, but in production, I keep getting redirected to the login page. Wanting to have it run through proxy, how do I do that?

When I make a regular HTTP request on my server:

```
Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://www.linkedin.com/in/SOMETHING'))
```

I get

```
=> "<html><head>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nwindow.onload = function() {\n  var domain = document.domain;\n  var newDomainIndex = 0;\n  if (domain.substr(0, 6) == \"touch.\") {\n    newDomainIndex = 6;\n  }\n  else if (domain.substr(0, 7) == \"tablet.\") {\n    newDomainIndex = 7;\n  }\n  if (newDomainIndex) {\n    domain = domain.substr(newDomainIndex);\n  }\n  window.location = \"https://\" + domain +  \"/uas/login?trk=sentinel_org_block&session_redirect=\" + encodeURIComponent(window.location);\n}\n</script>\n</head></html>\n"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843482/accessing-linkedin-public-pages-using-python). As mention [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/heroku-requests-return-999), LinkedIn do not allow direct access. Most likely they have blocked your server's IP address. You will have to use their APIs.