# Accessing LinkedIn public pages using Python

Tags: python, http, heroku, python-requests

I want to access my publicly available LinkedIn page. On my local machine, following code works:

```
import requests
url = "http://de.linkedin.com/pub/ankush-shah/73/9/982"
html = requests.get(url).text
print html
```

And it gives the correct html of my profile.

But when I execute the same code on my Heroku server, I (guess) am redirected to somewhere and gets [this](http://pastebin.com/QP1PS25Q) html.

Also, when I try with urllib2 on the heroku server:

```
import urllib2
url = "http://de.linkedin.com/pub/ankush-shah/73/9/982"
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

This throws an [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 999: Request denied](http://pastebin.com/Bx4ScT9x)

As I am using virtualenv, all the libraries on my local machine are exactly similar to the one installed on heroku server. Does LinkedIn blocks HTTP requests from servers like Heroku? Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not test for this directly ? Change the user agent on the request on the Heroku server to match the user agent from the other machine.

Comment: You mean something like this: 
   requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
This works on my local machine but still not on heroku.

Comment: There's no platform information in that user agent string. Try a string from [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/).

Comment: I tried couple of strings from there but still no luck.

Comment: Hang on. If Heroku is a hosted service, it has a static IP range (probably). Perhaps LinkedIn has IP blocked Heroku itself. This means you might need to proxy (or not use Heroku).

Comment: Yes, you are right. LinkedIn do not allows for such requests: https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/heroku-requests-return-999

Comment: You should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mention [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/heroku-requests-return-999), LinkedIn do not allow direct access. They have blacklisted Heroku's IP address and the only way to access the data is to use their APIs.

Comment: @Ankush_Shah : Did they remove the Ip-Adress from their blacklist after a while ?

Comment: i am not aware of it as I switched to use their API which is way better than directly scrapping data. so i doubt if they have any reason for removing the blacklisted ip addresses.