# Has LinkedIn blocked Google App Engine ip?

Tags: google-app-engine, linkedin-api

```
2015-10-16 23:42:55.024
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.linkedin.com
D 2015-10-16 23:42:55.060
"POST /uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1" 999 None
```

Getting an error on using social login via linkedin (using their api) on my appengine app. Same thing with another app I built on appengine. That can't be a coincidence. Both happening today at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "HTTP/1.1 999 Request denied" response from LinkedIn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571419/how-to-avoid-http-1-1-999-request-denied-response-from-linkedin)

Comment: it's not a duplicate, this is using the linkedin api, i believe that other post refers to direct access

Comment: this isn't so much debug as 'omfg people are screaming at me because the login is not working' :) And it seems to have happened without me making any changes to the site and it is happening across more than one site. So i guess more a question of 'anyone else got this now or ever had this on appengine?'

Comment: Could be you're blocked. Apparently [LinkedIn blocked Amazon EC2 and other IP ranges](https://github.com/yatish27/linkedin-scraper/issues/44) as well.

Comment: It looks like they've done the same thing. I have that same problem - it works on my local machine but not on appengine. They must have blocked the entire ip range for google cloud or something crazy. How on earth do I tell them?

Comment: It is now working. They have either unblocked it or it was a temporary problem. Hard to say which.

Comment: Hi folks - sorry about the inconvenience this caused. Can you verify if you're still running into this issue today? We're working to find the root cause of the block from a few days ago

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working fine now. It seemed to have been blocked for only a few hours as far as I can tell.

Comment: @KamyarMohager This problem has been hitting me in the past few days. It lasts for about a day where no-one can log in to my appengine app for the day, then it goes away for a day or two, but it just came back today. You really shouldn't be blocking App Engine from the LinkedIn API if you want people to use LinkedIn API. Please fix.

Comment: @kamyar-mohager Yes, it seems to be back. The same problem.

Comment: Hi all, our team is currently investigating this and will respond to this thread with any updates. Thanks

Comment: Hi everyone, our internal team has identified and fixed the issue. Please confirm that you're no longer receiving the 999 errors. We're also investigating further as to why this happened so that we can avoid any interruptions in the future. Sorry for the trouble it caused

Comment: There does still appear to be a problem. If you go to https://lovethisideaapp.appspot.com/ (which is google cloud / app engines development domain) and click sign up and click linkedin, it still appears blocked. When I try it on my local machine, it works fine. So, I guess it is still blocked.

Comment: Indeed, we are still blocked too. Error 999

Comment: Can one of you share the exact 999 response you received from our servers? The more recent the better so it can help us track down root cause

Comment: This is the exact return:
POST /uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1" 999 None

Comment: just tried again and it appears to be fixed. WOOOOOOOT!!

Comment: @KamyarMohager, It's fixed today, but will it block us again tomorrow? Support instructed me to email the error to developeraccess@linkedin.com, which I did 9 days ago and never got a response. Also it's hard to post the exact error, because the error response is an HTML page with Javascript on it. So I can tell you the error says: "Request denied Sorry, we are unable to serve your request at this time due to unusual traffic from your network connection." Then there's a field for Reason Codes, IP, URL, and Time, but these aren't filled in on my system due to it requiring javascript.