# Linkedin is doing a google cloud / App Engine block

Tags: google-app-engine, linkedin-api, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to login using LinkedIn on my site on Google App Engine. It was all working until today. Now I get a request denied error when trying to login using Linkedin. It works on the local server, it does not work on App Engine.

I'm using a boilerplate on Googles App Engine platform. I did not write this code but it has not changed so I don't think it is the code.

```
HTTP/1.1" 999
Error 500: No JSON object could be decoded


    elif provider_name == "linkedin":
        callback_url = "%s/social_login/%s/complete" % (self.request.host_url, provider_name)
        authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(
            self.app.config.get('linkedin_api'),
            self.app.config.get('linkedin_secret'),
            callback_url,
            [linkedin.PERMISSIONS.BASIC_PROFILE, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.EMAIL_ADDRESS])
        authentication.authorization_code = self.request.get('code')
        access_token = authentication.get_access_token()
        link = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
        u_data = link.get_profile(selectors=['id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address'])
        user_data = {
            'first_name': u_data.get('firstName'),
            'last_name': u_data.get('lastName'),
            'id': u_data.get('id'),
            'email': u_data.get('emailAddress')}
        self.session['linkedin'] = json.dumps(user_data)
```

Comment: Ok, it seems to be working now. I don't know whether I should take this post down now. If someone else comes across the same problem, it might help to notify them that waiting a couple of hours can do the job.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33180672/2213940

Comment: Hi folks - sorry about the inconvenience this caused. Can you verify if you're still running into this issue today? We're working to find the root cause of the block from a few days ago

Comment: It's cool, it's fixed now. I can login using linkedin.